# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting '(

Tags: php, date

Ok so im trying to have php check if the date on file is more than that of the current date if not i want it to echo a message but i keep getting this error. Please help!

```
<?php
$infosql = "SELECT * FROM premiersounds_users WHERE customer_id = $id";
$inforesult = mysql_query($infosql) or die(mysql_error());
$info = mysql_fetch_array($inforesult);

//Get date from database
echo $info['party_date'];

//Get current date from server
$format="%m/%d/%y";
$c_date=strftime($format);
//set sessions
$_SESSION['current_date'] = $c_date;
$_SESSION['party_date'] = $p_date;
echo $c_date;

//Check is Current date = lockout date
if $c_date <= $p_date { header("location:/Pages/my_info.php"); } else {echo 'Your account is locked out because your event is too close to allow online editing. Please contact your DJ.';}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried "SELECT * FROM premiersounds_users WHERE customer_id = " + $id; ?

Comment: @ysrb: That's not even the line he notes is failing. Plus the variable is inside of double quotes, so it will accomplish the same thing as concatenation.

Comment: Are you missing <?php in your code, or just in what you posted?

Comment: Just in what missing the connection information is above that with the <?php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if $c_date < $party_date`

needs to be:

`if( $c_date < $party_date )`

Comment: Thank you so much i completely missed that 8)!

Comment: @TylerRadlick: No problem. You just need to diagnose your error a bit. T_VARIABLE is a token that PHP uses to represent the presence of a variable when it's parsing your script. So, since that was unexpected, and it was expecting a paren (, just look to the left of each of your variables, starting from the left, and asking yourself if a paren should logically be there or not. It helps to split your code up too. Don't jam it all on one line like that.

Comment: @Josh: Thanks for the advice im self teaching myself php so every bit helps!

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems

this should work

```
$infosql = "SELECT * FROM premiersounds_users WHERE customer_id = '$id'";
$inforesult = mysql_query($infosql) or die(mysql_error());
$info = mysql_fetch_array($inforesult);

//Get date from database
echo $info['party_date'];

//Get current date from server
  $format="%m/%d/%y";
 $c_date=strftime($format);
  $_SESSION['current_date'] = $c_date;
 echo $c_date;

//Check is Current date < lockout date

//Problem Line//
 if ($c_date <= $party_date) { header("location:/Pages/my_info.php"); } else {echo  'Your account is     locked out because you event is too close to allow online editing. Please contact your DJ.';}
```

this

```
customer_id = $id";
```

should be

```
customer_id = '$id'";
```

and this

```
if $c_date <= $party_date
```

should be

```
if ($c_date <= $party_date)
```